Vscode's integrated WSL terminal breaks when long lines are entered in the terminal prompt
To replicate the issue, open WSL in a VScode terminal and scroll through your terminal prompts with arrow keys. The terminal session still functions correctly but is visually more difficult to use.
Symptoms:

The displayed text breaks when the prompt is too long.
Thee cursor does not highlight where it is in reality.
Blank spaces appear at the start of the prompt.
The line wrapping overwrites itself.

Screenshot of the terminal with the cursor hovering over 'g', the left most character able to be highlighted over
I tried finding similar issues but was unable to find one that had a solution.
Similar issues:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116029
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117917

